# zsh: check whether $PWD is on tmpfs mounted filesystem

Tags: mount, zsh, proc, tmpfs

I would like to change my `zsh` prompt color, if `$PWD` is currently on `tmpfs` mounted filesystem.

Lets say for example, `/dev/shm` is a `tmpfs` filesystem. I can confirm that:

```
$ grep /dev/shm /proc/mounts 
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=26307700k 0 0
```

so, when I am in `/dev/shm`, I can do:

```
grep -q "^tmpfs $PWD tmpfs " /proc/mounts
```

But that will not work, if I stand in `/dev/shm/foo`, or `/dev/shm/foo/bar`, and so on.

How can I check whether `$PWD` is on a `tmpfs` filesystem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Linux, you should be able to do:

```
findmnt -no FSTYPE .
```

to return the type of the filesystem on `.`

The GNU implementation of `stat` (not zsh `stat` builtin) can also do it with:

```
command stat -fc %T .
```

So you could cache that information in an element of `$psvar` in a `chpwd` hook:

```
check_cwd_is_tmpfs() {
  if [[ $(command stat -fc %T .) = tmpfs ]]; then
    psvar[1]=red
  else
    psvar[1]=green
  fi
}
chpwd_functions+=(check_cwd_is_tmpfs)
check_cwd_is_tmpfs

PS1='%F{%1v}%~%F$ '
```